# Is my simpler shell snippet the same as original?

Tags: shell, posix, brace-expansion

I am in a process of doing a yearly review of my POSIX shell code.

I may have found one *weird* line, which I did not know better before:

#### original

```
[ $# -eq 3 ] && exit_code=$3 || exit_code=1
```

#### new code - simpler

```
exit_code=${3:-1}
```

---

Are these two approaches the very same with providing results?

Please elaborate if there is any difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two approaches seem to use different logic:

```
[ $# -eq 3 ] && exit_code=$3 || exit_code=1
```

This will, *if and only if*, the number of positional parameters (`$#`) is equal to exactly three, set the `exit_code` variable equal to the value of the third positional parameter; otherwise it shall be set equal to `1`.

```
exit_code=${3:-1}
```

This will set `exit_code` to the value of the third positional parameter (or to `1` if it is not set) regardless of whether there are *more than* three positional parameters.

---

To summarize:  The first will set `exit_code` to 1 if number of positional parameters is anything other than exactly three; the second is irrespective of the number of positional parameters.

Comment: I have clarified the closing summary.